# Angular 2 Correct syntax

Tags: angular

We have an entity called `operator` which has a relationship with an entity called `country` .We want to filter an operator list based on country name how can we write this filter from the operator ? What is the correct syntax ?

**html** :

```
[(ngModel)]="opFilter.country?.name"
```

**ts** :

```
opFilter: any = {  country?.name : '' };
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve can be done using a simple `pipe`.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'countryFilter' })
export class CountryFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(operators: Operator[], countryName) {
    return operators.filter(operator => operator.country === countryName);
  }
}
```

and bind it in your template like this:

```
<h2 *ngFor="let op of operators | countryFilter: country">{{op.name}}</h2>
```

Where `country` is a property containing the name of the country you want to filter.

Here is a full demo:
https://plnkr.co/edit/GTP6P0PCDudH3NmWkkJf?p=preview

Comment: I've tried these both on template side but I didn't get result     <td>
                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="opFilter.country.name " placeholder="country" class="form-control">
            
            </td>

Comment: can you please add the expected result to your question? I'll reformat my answer to match the expected result.

Comment: we want to display the list of operators in special country. so we added this filter : the user enter the country name (example: France) and the list of frensh operators will be displayed.This is my  operator.model.ts file :

Comment: import { Country } from '../country';
import { MarketShareResult } from '../market-share-result';
import { CompetitorOperator } from '../competitor-operator';
export class Operator {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public isAffiliate?: boolean,
        public consumed?: boolean,
        public selected?: boolean,
        public isPrimary?: boolean,
        public codePMN?: string,
        public name?: string,
        public codeCurrency?: string,
        public valueCurrency?: number,
        public country?: Country,
       }}

Comment: @MarwaZaied I edited question and added a plunkr to suit your needs.